# How to read from Cassandra using Apache Beam with some pre-conditions

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-beam

I am reading from a cassandra table using apache beam CassandraIO. I would like to know if there is a way that can help me to put some condition/filter before reading from cassandra. As the table volume will increase in future, it will take significant amount of time to read the whole table.

I have following PCollection which holds the count of a pCollection and I want this to use as a pre-condition to read from cassandra if count>0

```
PCollection<Long> countRecords = dataPCollection.apply(
        "Count", Count.globally());
```

I am reading from cassandra like this. As per CassandraIO.Read it should be always at the root of the pipeline. Is there any workaround for this?

```
PCollection<CassandraEntity> cassandraEntityPCollection = pipeline
        .apply("Fetching from Cassandra",
            CassandraIO.<CassandraEntity>read()
                .withCassandraConfig(cassandraConfigSpec)
                .withTable("data")
                .withEntity(CassandraEntity.class)
                .withCoder(SerializableCoder.of(CassandraEntity.class)));
```

Comment: Can you use "withQuery(String)" (https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/cassandra/CassandraIO.Read.html#withQuery-java.lang.String-) for that? In this case, you can add "LIMIT N" to your CQL

Comment: @AlexeyRomanenko Either reading entire table with read() or read with query, my requirement is to have a condition before reading. e.g. if countRecords > 0 only then I want to read from cassandra if it's 0 I'll skip reading from cassandra

Comment: Ok, please, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try to do something like this using conditional creating of `CassandraIO.Read` as an input for `CassandraIO.readAll()`:

```
PCollection<Long> countRecords = dataPCollection.apply(
        "Count", Count.globally());

PCollection<Scientist> output =
    countRecords.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<Long, CassandraIO.Read<CassandraEntity>>() {
          @ProcessElement
          public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {
            long numRecords = context.element();
            if (numRecords > 0) {
              context.output(CassandraIO.<CassandraEntity>read()
                  .withCassandraConfig(cassandraConfigSpec)
                  .withTable("data")
                  .withEntity(CassandraEntity.class)
                  .withCoder(SerializableCoder.of(CassandraEntity.class)));
            }
          }
        }))
        .apply(
            CassandraIO.<CassandraEntity>readAll().withCoder(SerializableCoder.of(CassandraEntity.class)));
```

Comment: getting following error with this approach
`com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 0:-1 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'`
`Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 0:-1 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'`

Comment: It seems there are some issues with ringRanges which caused invalid cql query and hence above exception. So, I created a custom SplitFn class as it's inner private in CassandraIO and used it before readAll() same as mentioned in expand() of Read Transform.
`.apply(ParDo.of(new SplitFn<>()))
.setCoder(SerializableCoder.of(new TypeDescriptor<Read< CassandraEntity>>() {}))
.apply(CassandraIO.<CassandraEntity>readAll()`